# kubernetes update secrets using imperative commands

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am creating kubernetes secrets using the below command

```sh
kubectl create secret generic test-secret --save-config --dry-run=client --from-literal=a=data1 --from-literal=a=data2 -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now, I need to add new literals using kubectl imperative command how to do that??
say eg:

```sh
kubectl apply secret generic test-secret  --from-literal=c=data3 -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

but gave the below error

Error: unknown flag: --from-literal
See 'kubectl apply --help' for usage.
error: no objects passed to apply

Any quick help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> add new literals using kubectl imperative command

When working with *imperative commands* it typically means that you don't save the change in a place outside the cluster. You can **edit** a Secret in the cluster directly:

```
kubectl edit secret test-secret
```

But if you want to *automate* your "addition", then you most likely save your Secret another place before applying to the cluster. How to do this depends on how you manage Secrets. One way of doing it is by adding it to e.g. [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) and then have it automatically injected. When working in an automated way, it is easier to practice *immutable* Secrets, and create new ones instead of mutating - because you typically need to redeploy your app as well, to make sure it uses the new. Using [Kustomize with secretGenerator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kustomize/) might be a good option if you work with immutable Secrets.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I am planning to use sealed secrets... https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets. Thinking of  a way to automate the literals to the existing secrets.

Comment: They have documentation on https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets#update-existing-secrets

Comment: yes "--merge-into" option do the trick.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `kubectl patch` imeperative command

**example**

```
    root@controlplane:~# kubectl patch secrets test-secret --type='json' -p='[{"op" : "replace" ,"path" : "/data/newkey" ,"value" : "bmV3VmFsCg=="}]'
    secret/test-secret patched
    root@controlplane:~# kubectl describe secrets test-secret 
    Name:         test-secret
    Namespace:    default
    Labels:       <none>
    Annotations:  <none>

    Type:  Opaque

    Data
    ====
    a:       5 bytes
    b:       5 bytes
    newkey:  7 bytes
```

**you need to pass encoded value, to encode/decode the new value of key you can use below command**

```
root@controlplane:~# echo "newValue" | base64
bmV3VmFsdWUK
root@controlplane:~# echo bmV3VmFsdWUK | base64 -d
newValue
```

**another option is to use `kubectl edit` but if you automate your code you can't use edit option**

```
kubectl edit secret test-secret
```